# Slavery in halacha today

Tags: halacha, slave-serve-eved-avadim, modern-times

Are all/any the halachos of slavery still in effect today? For example:

1. If a destitute Jewish person stole and did not have the money to repay, could a modern beis did sell him/her as a slave?
2. If a person wanted to sell himself as a slave would someone (living in America, for example) be allowed to buy him if it goes against the laws of the land?
3. If "Reuven" purchased a non-Jewish slave and then freed him would that slave need to go through the conversion process?

[slightly related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/were-slave-related-commandments-observed-in-america)

Comment: CYLOR!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: re: #2 No, Dinah D'malchus, Dinah.

Comment: @HodofHod But I bet the kinyan would be chal if he did it anyway.

Comment: @HodofHod it should still be chal just like buying anything else that is "illegal", no?

Comment: @Moshe you did say: _"be allowed to buy him"_, which is not the same as "will the kinyan take effect?".

Comment: @HodofHod good point. Touche

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On #1: the Gemara [(Erchin 29a)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=29&format=pdf) states, and Rambam [(Hil. Avadim 1:10)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=12&hilchos=73&perek=1&halocha=10&hilite=) cites it as halachah, that the rules of a Jewish slave apply only when the Yovel is in effect (i.e., when most Jews live in their designated tribal territories in Eretz Yisrael, a state of affairs that hasn't existed since the end of the First Temple era and almost certainly won't exist again until Moshiach's times).

([Shem Yosef to Rambam there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=53954&rid=13324) cites and discusses the opinion of Ritva, though, that the basic law is still in effect in the sense that a Jew sold as a slave would need a formal document of emancipation (get shichrur). However, this seems to be limited to a case where the person sells himself - Ritva [writes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39297&pgnum=206) that יכול הוא למכור עצמו לעכו"ם או לישראל - but not that beis din can do so.)