# freed slaves owe their redeemer (jews owe HaShem)

Tags: mitzvah, faith-bitachon-emunah

if freed slaves owe their redeemer (jews owe HaShem)
how do we look on america freeing slaves

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Can you provide support for freed slaves owing their redeemer?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/were-slave-related-commandments-observed-in-america

Comment: The US didn't free slaves. They just stopped enslaving them. There's a (huge) difference.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at *bnei yisroel* as "free" then we will not understand the true nature of *yetzias mitzrayim.* We were not "freed" in a complete sense -- we are *bnei chorin* in that we serve a different master. [This](http://www.torahweb.org/torah/2012/moadim/rsch_pesach.html) sums up OUR responsibility as *avdei hashem*.

You can look at the Emancipation of American slaves then, in a parallel light. Someone who is not a slave to a human master still owes the institution that emancipated him -- as citizens, freed slaves have to follow the laws of the overarching community placed there by the same power that freed them, the government.