# "Don't say 'lehavdil' between one Jew and another."

Tags: words, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, derech-eretz-manners, quotations, sources-mekorot

In today's [Parashat Hashavu'a Chat](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/520/parashat-hashavua-chat), I used the qualification "lehavdil" (*) to apply to a pun that jokingly and innocuously related the actions of [Datan and Aviram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dathan) to those of a community member here.

[Alex](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/14759/alex) [responded to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=2963906#2963906) that "They say that you don't say "lehavdil" between one Jew and another," but later indicated that he doesn't recall where he heard this.

- Have you seen a source for this rule?
- What is the reason for it?
- Does it really mean that we shouldn't use the word to distinguish between a wicked Jewish person and a righteous one? If so, why?

---

(*) "Lehavdil," literally "to separate," indicates that while two entities may be juxtaposed in conversation, we don't intend to equate them in terms of religious value. [For example](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/did-any-achronim-comment-on-the-american-revolutionary-or-civil-wars):

> Did ... great rabbinic thinkers of the 1800s ... comment on American slavery and/or the Civil War? (As Dostoevsky did, *lehavdil*?)

Comment: Have you seen a source that you *do* say *l'havdil* for anything in the first place? It seems like just a common phrase in the religious world, but not necessarily necessary as a "rule".

Comment: @jake, no I have no source for saying it. As far as I'm concerned, it's just a cultural convention that I find apropos at times. If someone wise and/or authoritative has some advice about when not to deploy it, I'm interested to hear about it.

Comment: I was just re-reading Abarbanel's Rosh Amanah this morning, and in the introduction, he uses the exact same line that came up in the chat, "שני אנשים עברים נצים", to describe R' Chasdai Crescas and R' Yosef Albo. Made me laugh. (He didn't say *l'havdil*, by the way.)

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73790/8775.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81530/5323

Comment: The Chida in [his diary](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21838&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=) uses "lehavdil" to contrast the sefer Ari Nohem with other sefarim that he saw in a particular place.

Answer (score 7):

It is mentioned in [Kovetz Sipurim on the Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40514&pgnum=20)

Comment: He mentions this in terms of contrasting religious Jews with irreligious Jews (or generic sinners). Perhaps the Rebbe would concede that "*l'havdil*" is appropriate with respect to notoriously wicked people like those mentioned in the OP.