# benefits of following Noahaich laws and 613 mitzovets

Tags: gentiles, mitzvah, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, noachide-laws

As I read on mi yodeya, that following the 613 mitzovet is a nessesary for righteous jews, and I also know that this task is very difficult, but the seven mitzovet of Noahich laws are easy, and the I know that the follower of the 613 mitzovet will definitely have a portion in Olam Haba and the person who is gentile and following the seven noahiche laws will also have portion in the Olam haba, then my question is , Why to not follow the seven laws of Noaha, these laws are easy and after that there is no binding to follow any thing, and after all the follower of the 613 mitzovet and the bne noahaich both will have good portion in olam haba, then why we should put ourselves in more pains by following the 613 mitzovets, I am sorry if some thing wrong in my question, I just want to ease my mind.

Comment: Is your question: would a gentile be better off following the 613 instead of just the 7?

Comment: Is you question from the perspective of a Jew or a gentile? Jews are obligated to follow the 613, whether or not it is difficult; gentiles are not obligated in the 613 at all.

Comment: Perhaps there is a greater reward for a gentile who converts and observes all 613 laws than for one who simply follows the seven Noahide laws. The more you do, the more payoff you get. The only difference is that once you're a Jew, the 613 are mandatory (no option to follow just 7). But for non-Jews, 7 is all that's asked of them.

Comment: @Monica Cello, my question is as a both a Gentile and as a Jew, my question is, "If the seven Noahiche laws are equally beneficial, then why to follow those 613 mitzovets ?. if the benefit of both the 613 mitzovets and Noahaich laws is same, then i think it is easier to follow the Noahaich mitzovets to benefit from the portion in olam haba.

Comment: @Ishrat thanks for clarifying.  See Isaac's answer; the bottom line is that if you're a gentile you get no extra benefit from the 606 (God only requires the 7 of you), and if you're a Jew you don't get to opt out.  Whether there's merit in converting in order to get the responsibility and benefit of the full 613 is an interesting question (but maybe not the one you asked?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret this question correctly, it is based on the misconception that a person becomes a Jew and therefore obligated to keep 613 mitzvot by virtue of adopting the Jewish creed, just as a person would, [*lehavdil*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13246/2), become a Christian by virtue of adopting the Christian creed.

Actually, being a Jew, in this sense, is a matter of nationality rather than of belief. One is a member of the Jewish Nation and therefore obligated to keep all of the Mitzvot, [if either](http://www.jewfaq.org/whoisjew.htm) one is born of a Jewish mother or one undergoes a "conversion" process. This [conversion](http://www.jewfaq.org/gentiles.htm#Conversion) is more like becoming a citizen of a new country than simply adopting a belief system. People who are members of this nation through one of these two avenues are made responsible by God, whether they like it or not, to fulfill the 613 mitzvot.

Now, the argument that you make is certainly a valid one - to someone who is considering conversion to become a Jew. In fact, it is one of the arguments that any rabbi the potential convert approaches will pose to that person: Why adopt more responsibility? Why not just be a really good follower of the laws you're already obligated in?

Comment: Shalom and Thanks Isaac Moses for kind reply.

Comment: @Ishrat, to you as well - Shalom, and you're welcome. If you are interested in learning more about this topic, I recommend the two links to JewFAQ articles I embedded in the second paragraph, as well as the rest of http://www.jewfaq.org.

Comment: I will definitely read the JewFAQ articles, and if I need any clarifications on my questions I will definitely write, and I will be around this site, actually I like mi yodeya because it is more informative.