# Meaning of abbreviation tblch"t / tblch"a

Tags: hebrew, language, kavod, acronyms

What do these abbreviations stand for? I have seen them beside the names of righteous females. Does it mean that she should have long life? What is the equivalent for males?

Comment: Please edit in where you typically see this abbreviation. I gather you see this in Hebrew, not in "transl-English".

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317/5323

Comment: @DanF Indeed, it was translengish

Comment: @Shokhet Wow, that is useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See p. 322 of this [Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=uKIi0GU_Z5EC&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=tibadel%20lechaim&source=bl&ots=jrdgWN6eUL&sig=C7il0r1wzvom9G_YjDOiYfN-6Fk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj59IaS-4jTAhXp34MKHR-kBz0Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=tibadel%20lechaim&f=false). The Hebrew abbrevaiation is יבדל"א for males and תבדל"א for females.

Loose transliteration - *TiBadel/YiBadel Lecha'im Arukhim* meaning "May s/he live long, on the contrary".

The alternate version you mentioned (tblch"t) stands for the same, except that *Arukhim* is switched with *Tovim*, meaning "good life."

The expression is used when referring to a living male or female in the context of mentioning a deceased person. For example, at a speech, one might say, "We recall Aunt Esther, *aleha Hashalom* (peace be upon her). And we are thrilled to see Grandma Royza, *tibadel lechaim Arukhim* with us, here, today."

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13246

Comment: @msh210 Not quite related, IMO. That link is comparing two Jews, directly, who are both living. This situation, while mentioning two Jews, is actually using a form of "lehavdil" not for comparing the behaviors of two Jews but rather, I sense the "tibadel" term is used to explain an actual situation or timing. Namely, has passed, the other one is still alive. Or, am I completely missing the use of "tibadel" in this wish?