# Did Rabbi Akiva Go To Africa?

Tags: talmud-gemara, names, geography, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, maseches-rosh-hashana

The Gemara in Rosh Hashana 26a says:

> ואמר רבי עקיבא כשהלכתי לאפריקי...
>
> Rabbi Akiva said: when I went to Afriki

Is this referring to the continent of Africa?

Was Africa in this time period known by that name?

Are there any other Gemaras which talk about a trip to Africa that the Tanaim went on?

Comment: טט פת בלשון אפריקי Did you try a simple search for the word? https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=003922636974222575695%3Adxq675sw--g&ie=Windows-1255&hq=inurl%3A%2Fb%2F&q=%EC%E0%F4%F8%E9%F7%E9&sa=+%E7%F4%F9%21+#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99&gsc.page=1

Comment: @DoubleAA bkitzur, I looked in physical indexes but not a word search

Comment: The word _germamia_ appears in the Gemara and the Vilna Gaon corrects it to say _germania_, in reference to Germany, so I wouldn't be surprised if Africa appeared as well.

Comment: Mihi ne illud quidem accidit, ut Alexandrino atque Africano bello interessem. But I had not even the good fortune to share in the Alexandrian or African war. -- From Book 8 of Gallic Wars, by Julius Caesar

Comment: @Chaim cool! So in tannaic times Africa was th established name.

Comment: I think place names are often a hard problem.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47480/source-for-africans-being-caananites/47481#comment124900_47481 "Afriki in Chazal usually refers to Phrygia, not to Africa."

Comment: On that same page, R'Akiva says he went to Gaul. The safest way to get from North Africa to France would be through Sicily and Italy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! we definitely find this name in other Rabbinic literature. See Sanhedrin 94a. Yerushalmi Sheviis chapter 6.

Yitzchak Meitlis in the appendix to his book *Excavating the Bible* writes that this refers to Africa as the same story is found in the works of Procopius (Byzantine historian) where it is related that the Canaanites were afraid of Joshua Bin Nun (Girgashites according to Yerushalmi) and settled in Libya.

Comment: This answer might also be helpful for discussion in  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47480

Comment: So they are the berbers?